# Ошибка ajax error-datatables warning: table id -example

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

я совсем зеленый и мне нужно помощь. Мне нужно с помощью json сформировать datatable из нескольких структур данных. На данный момент застрял на этой ошибке. Если поможете + к карме

Функция в контроллере формирующая json.

```
  [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Lowx()
        {
            var query = db.Infos.
                Include(x => x.Profile).
                Include(x => x.Cars).
                ToList();

            return Json(new { data = query });
        }
```

таблица и ajax запрос

```
  <table class= "table" id="example" data-source="lowx">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th>first name</th>
                <th>last name</th>
                <th>middle name</th>
                <th>birthday</th>
                <th>carname</th>
                <th>carnumber</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>

    </table>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (data) {
         $("#example").DataTable({
  ajax: {
      url: '@Url.Action("Lowx")',
      type: 'GET',

      dataSrc: ""

  },
  columns: [
    { data: "FirstName", name: "FirstName" },
    { data: "LastName", name: "LastName" },
    { data: "MiddleName", name: "MiddleName" },
    { data: "BirthDate", name: "BirthDate" },
    { data: "CarName", name: "CarName" },
    { data: "CarNumber", name: "CarNumber" }
  ]
});
```

в консолu ошибка: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: Статус-код 500 в означает что произошло исключение. Для того, чтобы поймать в отладчике обработанное исключение, необходимо отключить опцию [Только мой код (Just my code)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn457346.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) в Visual Studio, и убедиться что в [настройках исключений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger) установлена галочка напротив пункта Common Language Runtime Exceptions. После этого, запускайте сайт в режиме отладки (F5), и воспроизводите ситуацию, которая приводит к исключению.

Comment: @Uranus а с фукнциями json и ajax все праильно?

Comment: @Uranus я отключил just my code но ничего не произошло. Также сначла loading , потом ошибка и no data valiables

Comment: Internal Server Error означает что исключение есть. Но я возможно ошибаюсь. Если вы запустили сайт из студии (клавишей F5), то студия должна выводить в окне Output все что происходит. В том числе и исключение. Output открывается так: Debug/Windows/Output.